# how do you create and run a dbt project with docker - without a dockerfile

Tags: docker, dbt

i first pull an image:

```
docker pull ghcr.io/dbt-labs/dbt-bigquery:1.2.latest
```

i then try to make a container:

```
docker run --name dbt \
-p 8085:8085 \
-v /home/sqlboi/bigquery_bkup/:/usr/app/ \
--mount type=bind,source=/home/sqlboi/dbt_profiles/,target=/root/.dbt/ \
dbt-bigquery:1.2.latest \
init myfirstproject
```

couple questions:

1. do i need to already have a `profiles.yml` file in that dbt_profiles folder?
2. when i run that container command, it creates a project file in `/home/sqlboi/bigquery_bkup/dbt/` - but the container stops after it gets an error...is the container supposed to keep running for dbt even without an error?
3. when i try to run the project, i get another error:  `fatal: Not a dbt project (or any of the parent directories). Missing dbt_project.yml file` - but the `dbt_project.yml` file can be found in `/home/sqlboi/bigquery_bkup/dbt/` after it was created by `init`, so how can i include a path to this?

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Note that *question* is singular, not plural - it's not a *numbered list of different questions* site. You may want to go back and re-read the [help] pages to better understand how the site works.

Comment: A Docker container wraps a single process (so (2), when that process exits with an error, the container exits too), and usually the image it runs is a complete built and packaged application ("without a Dockerfile" usually isn't correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems here:

The command is `dbt init`, not `init`. That command will create your profiles.yml for you (along with a dbt_project.yml file and some sample project files). But…

After creating the profile, `dbt init` will exit with code 0, so your container will stop anyway. dbt is a CLI utility, so it might be better for you to launch an interactive shell in your container instead of running a single command. But…

dbt doesn’t do anything unless you have a project with .sql and .yml files that define your transformations. You will need to get those files into your container. And you’ll need a Dockerfile for that